# ArcGIS WebApp Builder filter widget problem

Tags: sql, arcgis-online, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I developed a WebApp using ArcGIS Online and my application visualizes a couple of organizations providing different services for various customers. I created filters using the Filter Widget to allow users to visualize organizations on the map that provide services under the selected category (X, Y, Z) and for a certain type of customer (A, B, C). My filters are working properly; however, there is a little problem I have not been able to resolve. Currently, if the user selects a type of service (X) and a type of customer (A), the application shows them the union set (organizations providing services under category X OR for customer A. What I would like the map to show is the intersection set (organizations providing services under category X AND for customer A). I have not found this parameter in the Filter Widget settings. What would be the solution to get the intersection set and not the union?

Comment: Did you use the drop down to select `Display feature in the layer that match all of the following expressions` (or if using a set, `all of the following expressions`). Point being, when constructing, does it say ANY (or) or does it say ALL (and)?

Comment: Currently, Display features that match ANY of the filters is selected in the Filter Widget menu. When I select Display features that match ALL of the filters, the webmap app does not render anything.